# How can I determine whether the file was successfully downloaded from amazon s3 using boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

The following downloads the file from s3 but how can I know whether the file was successfully downloaded? The [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file) were of no help in this.

The code is:

```
download_file = self.bucket.download_file(kch_file_to_be_downloaded_key, destination_of_kch_file_to_be_downloaded)
```

Comment: You'd [check the integrity](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Martijn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) answer:

[This](https://gist.github.com/nateware/4735384) has code which checks the md5 checksum of a local file and compares it with the md5 checksum of the object in S3.

This might be a decent starting point.